# Why Opacity is not working in Blend?

Tags: color

I want Blend transparent to solid color and use it in `DensityPlot`

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 0], 
      RGBColor[1, 0, 0, 1]}, #] &),PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But I don't want to use RGBColor, I want something like this

```
blendTransparent[color_]:=Blend[{Opacity[0,color], color}, #] &
```

So it can take any color and blend from transparent to solid. However, Opacity is not working in Blend. How to do it?

Comment: `Opacity[]` does not work in `Blend[]`. You already know you can use the alpha argument for the `*Color[]` functions, and `Append[]` works well, so why not use it?

Comment: @J.M. Oh, yeah. I just come up with the solution. Thank you so much. This post is so trivial, I will delete it